# Save Excel File to Sharepoint in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint, azure-automation

I am trying to create an Excel spreadsheet in Powershell and then save it to a Sharepoint site using the PnP Powershell module. The following is the code I currently have:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application;
$excel.visible = $True;

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add();
$reportWksht = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1);
/*Create cell data and autosize*/

Add-PnPFile -Folder *Path to folder* -Stream *Excel file stream* -FileName "Excel.xlsx"
```

I am not sure if it is possible to turn the $excel object into a Stream or if Azure Automation Powershell will even allow me to manipulate an Excel file.

I am unable to save this Excel file anywhere, it has to be uploaded directly from Powershell to SharePoint.

Any help you can give me on this is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try just saving the file to the URL? `$workbook.SaveAs('https://company.sharepoint.com/path/to/file.xlsx')` That works for me just fine in my testing.

Comment: Hi, `samehope92`, I posted an answer to end this question.